# Find indexes that fail numpy.assert_almost_equal

Tags: python, numpy

I'm dealing with large 3D arrays like (110,80,817) and wanting to compare two arrays in some unit tests.  However, the default output from `numpy.assert_almost_equal` doesn't help me track down the errors very easily.  For example:

```
>                   raise AssertionError(msg)
E                   AssertionError:
E                   Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
E
E                   (mismatch 0.0314621119395%)
E                    x: array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
E                           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
E                           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],...
E                    y: array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
E                           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
E                           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],...
```

Is there a way to easily see which 3D indexes are failing this assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) combined with [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this

```
idx = zip(*np.where(~np.isclose(a, b, atol=0, rtol=1e-7)))
```

Now `idx` will be a list of all the indices `(x,y,z)` where the assertion fails.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help.